# Cron job for Django File

Tags: django, cron, django-custom-manager

I want to setup a Cron job to run a django file.

What I want to know is django-cron a good option for this? i.e. or are there any other apps that can be used?
If no, how to run a django file through command line ?

```
admin@ADMIN-PC ~/workspace/bolt (master)
$ python ./log/cron.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./log/cron.py", line 3, in <module>
    from account.models import UserProfile
ImportError: No module named account.models
```

I have set the following variable

```
admin@ADMIN-PC ~/workspace/bolt (master)
$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
```

I keep getting these errors as the files that are being referenced have direct imports

```
from foo.models import *
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Custom Command

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import pdb
import datetime

from too.models import UserProfile
from foo.api import end_all_foo_conversations


class Command(BaseCommand):
    # in minutes
    def handle(self,*args,**options):
        print datetime
```

The error I am getting while trying to run the command is as follows:-

```
'queryset': self.rel.to._default_manager.using(db).complex_fi
```

imit_choices_to),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_default_manager'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run it through `manage.py`.

Comment: @AkashDeshpande Your command looks fine, in what file is this error raised?

Comment: This error is raised when i run the command throught command line

Comment: @AkashDeshpande In what file? It prints filename in traceback.

Comment: It is realted to the imports that I am doing in the other files.

for eg. import foo.view something

This file i.e. foo.view not being in the same directory causes the import error. (At least that is what i think.) Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: @AkashDeshpande I can't answer without looking at source and it isn't related to your original quetion at all. It's another problem. Do some debugging yourself and if there are some problems ask another question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5650/discussion-between-akash-deshpande-and-drtyrsa)